# printing object stored in an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have an array storing some data in the following format

```
var arrayTest = [{
    "firstName": "SOUM!",
     "lastName": "Ghosh"
}, {
    "firstName": "Fred",
    "lastName": "Twilliger"
}, {
    "firstName": "Snoop",
    "lastName": "Krieg"
}

]
```

I am trying to parse each key items

here is my script

```
    var html = "";

$.each(arrayTest, function () {
    html + = this.firstName;
});

alert(html);
```

what am I doing wrong.

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/J2ssK/6/

Comment: f12 for the developer console. It will show your errors.

Comment: @CoryDanielson Unless you're on a mac, then it will just pump up the volume or something ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

So... you can't have a space between `+` and `=`

Comment: Ahh damn that was it. really simple. I cant believe I missed that. Thanks for pointing that out brian

Comment: Yeah, fella. The console is your best friend - it avoids all sorts of questions.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is so last century

```
var html = arrayTest.map(function(n) {
    return n.firstName;
}).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(arrayTest, function (i, row) {
    html += row.firstName;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J2ssK/8/